# while using useEffect hook i am getting this error on browser

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```js
const [cont, useCont] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://5.181.217.46/DesignFacility/useGETMethodForTheResponse/Arvind%20Baloda"
      )
      .then((resp) => {
        const res = resp.data;
        console.log(res);
        useCont(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

#### error

```
Line 18:9:  React Hook "useCont" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

Comment: this is hooks linting error.. please change useCont to setCont

Comment: I think this is just unfortunate naming. If you call it setCont instead of useCont this will be fine. React has rules about when you can use hooks, and the `use` pattern is how that is detected I think

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace:

```
const [cont, useCont] = useState([]);
```

by :

```
const [cont, setCont] = useState([]);
```